# Passing large data batches to Pug file from Node/Express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, pug

*Note that this has been edited since the initial posting*

I am building a Data Dashboard using NodeJs, Express, and Pug and have a question regarding the passing of data from NodeJs/Express to the Pug file.

I know that you can pass variables directly to the Pug file through express's local variables as seen below:

```
res.render('index', {title: 'This is the Title'});
```

My question is regarding the most efficient way of creating HTML using this data.
There are 3 main methods I am considering using and would like a more experienced insight into which may be the most suitable.

1. Dynamically generate elements in Javascript

The first option is to emit the data using Socket and then to create the HTML elements in Javascript using the data and appending them to the body.

My main worry with this option is that it may not be as efficient building large amounts of HTML in Javascript after the page has been rendered.

2. Create HTML Elements in Pug and supply data through Javascript

The second option I am considering is to create the elements with-in the Pug file (Only passing the number of elements) and then to supply the data through the Javascript after the page has rendered.

3. Create HTML elements completely in Pug

My final option is to pass all the data (Roughly 3 tables, around 5-10 rows with 5 columns of data) to the Pug file and to create the elements with the data inside the Template file.

I apologies if this question makes no sense, I'm relatively new to Pug, Express and Node but am finding myself improving every day. Any insights or tips/techniques would be extremely appreciated.

If theres any other information that may help, please do ask.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: This question is vague. You are asking about performance with "large" data sets, but how large are we talking about? Personally (some might disapprove), I avoid server-side rendering because I prever using each client's resources to build the page (with Angular) and only using Node for I/O operations, as you're currently doing, to keep it fast.

Comment: Apologies, I'm relatively new to StackOverflow but I do appreciate the response. The data I am referencing isn't as large as I originally made it out to be, maybe only consisting of 30-50 rows returned from a database converted into a JSON. My main reason for worrying is that in all examples of Express Locals I have seen, it has only been used for simple variables such as title and names. The current system is building the majority of the HTML in the JS which I assumed would take more of a hit on performance than it being rendered in Pug.